# Typescript infer variable type class

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have 3 interfaces:

```
export interface Foo {a:string}
export interface Foo2 extends Foo {b:boolean}
export interface Foo3 extends Foo {c:number}
```

How do I make a class assignation without error?

```
class Goo {
  fooVar: Foo | Foo2 | Foo3;

  constructor() {
    this.fooVar.c = 0; <------ ERROR!
  }
}
```

All help is welcome :)

Comment: Possibly `fooVar` should use intersection rather than union types (`Foo & Foo2 & Foo3`), but it also depends on what you're doing specifically

Answer (score 1):

There are several options (If `fooVar` is really supposed to be either one of `Foo`, `Foo2` or `Foo3`).

The simplest solution is a type assertion :

```
  class Goo {
    fooVar: Foo | Foo2 | Foo3 = {
      a: ""
    };

    constructor() {
      (this.fooVar as Foo3).c = 0
    }
  }
```

If `c` is already in `fooVar` and you only want to assign it if it already exist (ie `fooVar` is already `Foo3`) you can use an `in` type guard:

```
  class Goo {
    fooVar: Foo | Foo2 | Foo3 = {
      a: "", c: -1
    };

    constructor() {
      if('c' in this.fooVar) this.fooVar.c = 0
    }
  }
```

If you don't mind changing the object reference you can use spread :

```
  class Goo {
    fooVar: Foo | Foo2 | Foo3 = {
      a: "", 
    };

    constructor() {
      this.fooVar = {...this.fooVar, c: 0 }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Wouldn't be better to use intersection or extending types? `type Foo extends...`

Comment: @kinduser I am not really sure what he is trying to achieve ... the question asked how you can assign a property on a union type (at least in my reading) I tried to offer options for that.